# New featurs in SharePoint 2016 and office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, 2016, features

Hi what are the new features added in SharePoint 2016 as per office 365 and SharePoint online and adfs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding new features added in SharePoint 2016 as per office 365 and SharePoint online

- Document conversations in OneDrive for Business and SharePoint Online
- SharePoint Online Encryption "At Rest"
- Site folders in OneDrive for Business and SharePoint Online
- Data Loss Prevention in SharePoint Online
- New Experience for SharePoint lists / Library.
- Use Microsoft Flow to automate workflows
- Use PowerApps to connect SharePoint lists and Libraries as a data source
- SharePoint mobile app for iOS
- Upload and manage videos with Office 365 Video

[image]

For more details check

- [Thrilling New Updates in SharePoint for Office 365](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/new-sharepoint-features-for-office-365)
- [What’s new in Microsoft SharePoint Online](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-s-new-in-Microsoft-SharePoint-Online-02449ef0-027e-4089-8717-f0ae7ea58029)

If you asked about new features for SharePoint 2016 on-prem , Mr @Waqas have mentioned this also I have summaries most of the new and deprecated features at [Simply, What’s new and deprecated features in SharePoint Server 2016 ?](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/05/29/simply-whats-new-and-deprecated-features-in-project-server-2016/)

Answer (score 1):

For sharepoint 2016, there are many new features, some are as fellow

- MinRole topology
- Durable links, Resource-based URLs now retain links when documents are renamed or moved in SharePoint.
- Encrypted Connections,SharePoint Server 2016 supports TLS 1.2 connection encryption by default.
- Fast Site Collection Creation,The Fast Site Collection Creation feature is a rapid method to create site collections and sites in SharePoint.
- Filenames - expanded support for special characters,SharePoint Server 2016 now supports using some special characters in file names that were blocked in previous versions.
- Identify and search for sensitive content,SharePoint Server 2016 now provides the same data loss prevention capabilities as Office 365.
- Large file support,SharePoint Server 2016 now supports uploading and downloading files larger than 2,047 MB.
- Mobile experience,SharePoint Server 2016 offers an improved mobile navigation experience.
- New controls for working with OneDrive for Business
- New Recycle Bin in OneDrive and Team sites

[Read complete list here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt346121(v=office.16).aspx)